# Is there a way to add a title to a table in R

Tags: r, datatable

I'm super new to R and I'm struggling to create a header above the column names.

colnames(system_table) <- c("System 1", "System 2", "System 3","System 4")

I want to add a title above these that says "All Systems" but I can't seem to find the function to do so.

Comment: Do you want to store the data on the object, or is it just for display? If the latter this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648431/get-a-second-header-with-the-units-of-columns. But data.frames in R natively can only have one set of headers and do not store table labels. You'd have to create a custom class to track that data (or find a package that does that already -- though I do not know of any)

Comment: I wanted to store, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in `Rmarkdown`:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(formattable)

system_table <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3),
                           v2 = c(3,2,5),
                           v3 = c(5,3,2),
                           v4 = c(3,2,1))

colnames(system_table) <- c("System 1", "System 2", "System 3","System 4")

formattable(system_table) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F, caption = "All Systems")

```
````

Output:

[image]